# Что лучше 1 большой запрос к БД или порционно?

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных, sqlalchemy

Работаю с проектом, в котором периодически происходят запросы к БД. Раньше делал 1 запрос в начале работы скрипта и в памяти висела вся БД. Соответственно потом по ходу работы скрипта - проходило все быстро, единственное только 1 НО - это время в начале выборки. Потом сделал адресные выборки, т.е. что надо было - то и брал из БД и увидел, что нагрзузка стала подниматься на сервер.

Теперь соответственно сам вопрос: кто работает тоже с БД как Вы подходите к таким решениям? Что лучше сделать 1 большой запрос или брать порционно? Или третий вариант запоминать порционные запросы?

PS:

1. В качестве  СУБД использую MySQL. Работа с БД проходит через SQLAlchemy.
2. Реляционная модель БД, 3НФ. I:II - 1:M | II::III - 1:M .
3. В момент времени надо знать возможные комбинации ключей второй таблицы в зависимости от Главной таблицы, чтобы потом по выбранному случайному ключу выбрать случайный ключ из диапазона 3 таблицы

Comment: Всё сильно зависит от вашей конкретной задачи, нужных вам выборок и соответствующей оптимизации настроек БД

Comment: @andreymal, Ну предположим (сделаю аналогию), у меня БД, которая содержит таблицу домов, каждый уникальный дом имеет множество квартир, а в каждой квартире живет множество человек. И мне дается 10 семей и мне надо найти в какой квартире они живут, какого дома. Раньше я делал выборку и формировал словари. Соответственно обращался к элементам по ключам. Сейчас же , находясь в доме у семьи ищу конкретный дом, в конкретном доме делаю запрос к конкретной квартире, где и узнаю какое количество людей живет =) Примерно так дела обстоят)

Comment: А для соответствующих столбцов семьи-квартиры-дома вы добавили индексы, чтобы база могла быстро их искать?

Comment: @andreymal, да. Обычная модель реляционной БД. 1 таблица ко 2ой 1:M, 2 таблица к 3ей тоже 1:M. БД приведена к 3НФ

Comment: Я считаю что за один запрос будет не значительно быстрее, но нужно смотреть на конкретую задачу

Comment: Тогда, возможно, есть смысл попробовать запихнуть всю нужную выборку в один запрос с INNER JOIN'ами?

Comment: @andreymal, да но дело в том, что я не знаю какие именно 10 семей мне надо. В момент времени мне просто говорят, что меня телепортируют 10 раз. и телепортнувшись в 1ый раз - я смотрю по сторонам и вижу у какого дома нахожусь - по его номеру я делаю выборку всех квартир и только потом мне говорят случайный номер квартиры. Узнав его - я делаю запрос к "Квартирам", по номеру квартиры и только после этого узнаю количество жителей =)

Comment: При нормально настроенных индексах нет никакого смысла в предварительной информации о номере дома без знания номеров квартир. Если есть правильные индексы, выборка по номеру дома и номерам квартир будет моментальная. Ну, если только вам инфу о доме надо заранее выводить, не зная квартир, тогда можно по отдельности, всё больше уточняя критерии выборки.

Comment: Ну и в целом смотря сколько в базе всего этого добра. Если база не обновляется на ходу и легко помещается в память и вы правильно умеете быстро искать в памяти, то можно и в память всю базу заранее загрузить

Comment: @CrazyElf, т.е. загрузить БД переменную, когда проект запускается? И обращаться к ней, чтобы не обращаться к БД во время запроса клиента? Хм.. Интересный подход. Я загружал всю БД только  момент запроса пользователя. Попробую потестить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-общем, после многих тестов было решено оставить обращение к БД порционно.

Хоть количество обращений к БД увеличилось, но средние показатели установили, что процессор в среднем нагружается меньше, ОП не переполняется соответственно ошибка 413 стала появляться меньше. Хотя она полностью была решена путем добавления файла подкачки - после него 413 полностью пропала!

- Приложение стало работать быстрее (на 1-2 секунды)
- Пропали ошибки 502 и 413.
- Средняя нагрузка на сервере стала стабильная (дельта тестов показывала 1-2 %, в то время как с выгрузкой всей БД в память - скачки были до 10% !)